# I have a problem with Media Player when playing the audio, it does not stop even when I exit the application How do I release this code?

Tags: java, android

```
enter code here
```

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
@Override

```
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            btPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

        }
    });

}
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private String convertFormat(int duration) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d"
            , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)
            ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating a Mediaplayer instance everytime. Make sure that instead of the instantiation is

```
MediaPlayer mp;// above the onCreate section
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.animal_kit);
```

instead of

`MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.animal_kit);`

Comment: mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mmgg);
        runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                handler.postDelayed(this, 500);

            }

        };